Getting Exception / Error while running a Test using testNG
Getting below error if I try to run the test using testNG -
[RemoteTestNG] failed to get TestNG version from class: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version "[WORKING]": non-numeric "[WORKING]"
[RemoteTestNG] now trying to parse the version from pom.properties
[RemoteTestNG] now trying to parse the version from MANIFEST.MF
[RemoteTestNG] parsing TestNG version at jar:file:///C:/Users/Shreyas%20Lembhe/Downloads/testng-7.10.2.jar!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.10.2
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
org.testng.TestNGException:
An error occurred while instantiating class test.SumValidation: Unable to make public test.SumValidation() accessible: module DemoProject does not "exports test" to module org.testng
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.createInstance(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:100)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.dispense(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:41)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.internal.objects.GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.dispenseObject(GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.java:41)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.internal.objects.GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.dispense(GuiceBasedObjectDispenser.java:31)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getDefaultInstance(ClassImpl.java:107)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.internal.ClassImpl.getObjects(ClassImpl.java:140)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.internal.IObject.lambda$objects$0(IObject.java:59)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.internal.IObject.objects(IObject.java:59)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.TestClass.getObjects(TestClass.java:150)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.TestClass.initTestClassesAndInstances(TestClass.java:126)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:118)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.TestClass.(TestClass.java:83)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:473)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:347)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:302)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.TestRunner.(TestRunner.java:222)
at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG7_9$1.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG7_9.java:35)
at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG7_9$DelegatingTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(RemoteTestNG7_9.java:68)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.ITestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(ITestRunnerFactory.java:52)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.SuiteRunner$ProxyTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:708)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.SuiteRunner.(SuiteRunner.java:197)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1365)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1339)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1199)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1112)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1079)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:293)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public test.SumValidation() accessible: module DemoProject does not "exports test" to module org.testng
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.throwInaccessibleObjectException(AccessibleObject.java:388)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:364)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:312)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.checkCanSetAccessible(Constructor.java:194)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.setAccessible(Constructor.java:187)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.instantiateUsingDefaultConstructor(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:178)
at org.testng@7.10.2/org.testng.internal.objects.SimpleObjectDispenser.createInstance(SimpleObjectDispenser.java:88)
... 29 more
Project structure -
src folder -> files (package)->Payload.java
src folder -> files (package)->ReUsableMethods.java
src folder -> test (package)->Basics.java
src folder -> test (package)->ComplexJsonParse.java
src folder -> test (package)->SumValidation.java
testng, restAssured and hamcrest dependencies / libraries are added in both of the below places -

Maven Dependencies (Using pom.xml & also tried with downloading and adding manually)

Referenced / Project libraries (Using Build Path-> Libraries->ModulePath->Add External JARs)


SumValidation.java -
package test;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import files.Payload;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;
public class SumValidation {
@Test
public void sumOfCourses() {
    JsonPath js=new JsonPath(Payload.coursePrice());
    int count=js.getInt("courses.size()");
    
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++) {
        int price=js.getInt("count["+i+"].price");
        int copies=js.getInt("count["+i+"].copies");
        int amount=price*copies;
        System.out.println(amount);
    }
}

}
Payload.java - (Used in above code in JsonPath line) -
package files;
public class Payload {
public static String addPlace() {
    return "{\r\n"
            + "  \"location\": {\r\n"
            + "    \"lat\": -38.383494,\r\n"
            + "    \"lng\": 33.427362\r\n"
            + "  },\r\n"
            + "  \"accuracy\": 50,\r\n"
            + "  \"name\": \"Frontline house\",\r\n"
            + "  \"phone_number\": \"(+91) 983 893 3937\",\r\n"
            + "  \"address\": \"29, side layout, cohen 09\",\r\n"
            + "  \"types\": [\r\n"
            + "    \"shoe park\",\r\n"
            + "    \"shop\"\r\n"
            + "  ],\r\n"
            + "  \"website\": \"http://google.com\",\r\n"
            + "  \"language\": \"French-IN\"\r\n"
            + "}\r\n"
            + "";
}

public static String coursePrice() {
    return "{\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "\"dashboard\": {\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "\"purchaseAmount\": 910,\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "\"website\": \"rahulshettyacademy.com\"\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "},\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "\"courses\": [\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "{\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "\"title\": \"Selenium Python\",\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "\"price\": 50,\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "\"copies\": 6\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "},\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "{\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "\"title\": \"Cypress\",\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "\"price\": 40,\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "\"copies\": 4\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "},\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "{\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "\"title\": \"RPA\",\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "\"price\": 45,\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "\"copies\": 10\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "},\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "{\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "\"title\": \"Appium\",\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "\"price\": 55,\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "\"copies\": 15\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "}\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "]\r\n"
            + "\r\n"
            + "}";
}

}
pom.xml -

4.0.0
DemoProject
DemoProject
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

src


maven-compiler-plugin
3.8.1

22




<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.10.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.10.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jcommander/jcommander -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jcommander</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

